# Pivot SQL from one column multi raw to multi column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to conevrt this sql table:

```
--------------
| Value       |
---------------
| first row   |
| second row  |
| third row   |
---------------
```

in something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Value       | 01       | 02          | 03        |
----------------------------------------------------
| first row   |first row | second row  | third row |
----------------------------------------------------
```

using pivot queries I can not recover data, being strings

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT Value
FROM Desc_sin ) AS Source
PIVOT
(MAX(Value) FOR Value IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS PVT;
```

or

```
SELECT 'Value'
[0], [1], [2],[3]
FROM
(SELECT Value
    FROM [Desc_sin]) AS st
PIVOT
(
max(Value)
FOR Value IN ([0], [1], [2],[3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: do you have sample data? `First row` means entire row or just string `First row`? if it is simple string, I am afraid that is not a candidate data can be pivoted

Comment: first row is a string example, it could be any string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VALUE column can be assigned in the final select

However, there is no GTD of ORDER without a proper sequence.  You may notice in the ORDER BY we have (Select NULL)

**Example**

```
Select Value=[01],*
 From  (
        Select Item=format(Row_Number() over(Order By (Select NULL)),'00')
              ,ItemValue = Value
         from  YourTable
       ) A
 Pivot (max(ItemValue) for Item in ([01],[02],[03])) P
```

**Returns**

```
Value       01          02          03
first row   first row   second row  third row
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below Approach

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp
;With CTe( Value)
AS
(
SELECT 'first row'  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'second row' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'third row'   
)
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM cte

DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(100)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT TOP 1 Value , STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+(Value)
                            FROM #temp FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS Col
)
SELECT DISTINCT Value,
        SPlit.a.value('/S[1]','nvarchar(1000)') AS [01],
        SPlit.a.value('/S[2]','nvarchar(1000)') AS [02],
        SPlit.a.value('/S[3]','nvarchar(1000)') AS [03]
FROM
(
SELECT Value, CAST('<S>'+ REPLACE(Col,',','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML ) As String
FROM CTE 
)c
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('S') AS SPlit (a)
```

Result

```
Value           01           02             03
---------------------------------------------------
first row    first row1  second row2     third row3
```